# What should be the time complexity of the given function in terms of Big O?

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
int find_peak (int n, int A []) {
    int left, right, lmid, rmid;
    left = 0;
    right = n - 1;
    while (left + 3 <= right) {
        lmid = (2 * left + right) / 3;
        rmid = (left + 2 * right) / 3;
        if (A[lmid] <= A[rmid])
            left = lmid;
        else
            right = rmid;
    }
    int x = left;
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i ++)
        if (A[i] > A[x])
            x = i;
    return A[x];
}
```

I was trying to solve this function for its BigO notation, but I am very confused about it. Is it O(log n) or something else? I can somewhat solve it in my head but I can't do it on properly.

Comment: Please indent yur code properly. This is barely readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the loop is cut roughly in half at each iteration

```
lmid = (2 * left + right) / 3;
rmid = (left + 2 * right) / 3;
if (A[lmid] <= A[rmid])
    left = lmid;
else
    right = rmid;
```

---

To be precise it's **log<sub>1.5</sub>(n)**, because the actual length `right-left` decreases only by **<sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>**, not halving the iterations. The complexity is still **O(log(n))**

You can try it here https://onlinegdb.com/rkI5gn3Xd

---

Thanks to chqrlie for prompting me to give a more detailed answer

Comment: You are a good salesman: 33% off! you pay roughly half the price :)

Comment: @chqrlie hahahahha not really. You're right, but my answer wasn't meant to be precise :)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the above code should be **O(log3n)** i.e...**logn** base **3**. because in the **while loop** the value of `rmid` always comes out as greater than `lmid`.So, for a given value of right i.e...`n`, the value of left will be reduced by a multiple of 1/3 at each iteration.

Comment: O(log3(n)) is the same as O(log2(n)) or O(Log(n)), these different logs differ only by a constant factor. Furthermore the loop only decreases the span by 1/3, the number of iterations is `log(right - left) / log(3/2)`